# WriteFile doesnt work without debug

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino, port, communication

I am trying to send arguments to my arduino. so i made this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 HANDLE serialPortHandler;
 char *comPort[8] =  {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
 char comPortName[5] = "COM";
 int i = 1;

int openPort(char *name){

    serialPortHandler = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    if(serialPortHandler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        return -1;
    }else{
        DCB dcb;
       FillMemory(&dcb, sizeof(dcb), 0);
       if (!GetCommState(serialPortHandler, &dcb)){
          return -1;
       }

       dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600 ;

       if (!SetCommState(serialPortHandler, &dcb)){
            return -1;
       }
    }
    return 1;
}

int writePort(char *lpBuf,DWORD dwToWrite){
        DWORD dwWritten;
     if(WriteFile(serialPortHandler, lpBuf, dwToWrite, &dwWritten, NULL)){
            while(dwWritten < dwToWrite);
            printf("User: %s, %d", lpBuf, dwWritten);  
            return 0;                                                                            
     }else{
           printf("Error");
           CloseHandle(serialPortHandler);
           return 1;
     }
     return 0;                               
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2)
            return 1;
    strcat(comPortName, comPort[0]);
    while(openPort(comPortName) < 0 && i < sizeof(comPort) / sizeof(int)){
        comPortName[3] = *comPort[i];
        //printf("%s", comPortName);
        i++;
        Sleep(0);
    }if(i >= sizeof(comPort) / sizeof(int)){
         printf("Cannot Find Port");
         scanf("%d");
         return 1;
    }
    printf("Port %s Is Opened - BaudRate 9600\n", comPortName);
    printf("Sent Frequency: %s\n", argv[1]);
    writePort(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
}
```

But it only works if i run it on debug mode and wait for a few moments at WriteFile.If i run it from cmd it doesnt output to my arduino.

Comment: `while(dwWritten < dwToWrite);` - this loops forever if the condition is true. Is that intended?

Comment: dwWritten is output of the function therefor it  can change through time. The variable is the amount of bytes sent. So the while loop is increasing and when the function sent all of it then dwWritten will be equle to dwToWrite and it will continue.

Comment: WriteFile() just copies bytes into the driver's transmit buffer, it takes a good deal of time to actually get them transmitted.  Without the debugger slowing down your program, the port will be closed *immediately* after you called WriteFile().  Because your program instantly terminates.  That prevents those buffered bytes from being sent.   Calling Sleep() for dwWritten milliseconds is hacky but probably works, better to call ClearCommError() in a loop so you can see the COMSTAT.cbOutQue field reach 0.  Now you know that the transmit buffer is empty so it is okay to close the port.

Comment: i changed the else after the WriteFile to look like this:

else{
       do{
           ClearCommError(serialPortHandler, &lpErr, &lpStat);
       }while(lpStat.cbOutQue > 0);
      fRes = true;
   }

Comment: @TatGonen No, it can't change except when you call the function.

Answer (score -1):

The `WriteFile` function has the ability to run asynchronously. Have you checked for this case?

From:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx

> If the function fails, or is completing asynchronously, the return value is zero (FALSE). To get extended error information, call the GetLastError function.

The WriteFile function returns when one of the following conditions occur:

- The number of bytes requested is written.
- A read operation releases buffer space on the read end of the pipe (if the write was blocked). For more information, see the Pipes section.
- An asynchronous handle is being used and the write is occurring asynchronously.
- An error occurs.

(Meta: Can't blockquote a bullet list, I guess)

Comment: He didn't open the port in asynchronous mode, so the point you quoted does not apply.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - Ah, I got caught up by the "works if i run it on debug mode and **wait for a few moments**" That made async sound like a good suspect, but requires an async handle, so you're probably right.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was it takes time to initiate these two things:
1.SetCommState(serialPortHandler, &dcb)

so i added Sleep before and it fixed the problem.